# How to set folder write-access permissions

Tags: vb.net, permissions, directory, basic

Heres my code

```
Dim FolderPath As String = "C:/folder"
Dim UserAccount As String = "(DESKTOP-T34R8TH\Users)"
Dim FolderInfo As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderPath)
Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
FolderAcl.AddAccessRule(New FileSystemAccessRule(UserAccount, FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit Or InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow))
FolderInfo.SetAccessControl(FolderAcl)
```

nothing happens. i want the folder to have a write permission.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a new DirectorySecurity object to the folder. You have to retrieve the existing one and modify it.

So instead of using

```
Dim FolderAcl As New DirectorySecurity
```

You should use

```
Dim FolderAcl As DirectorySecurity = FolderInfo.GetAccessControl()
```

See the MS documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.setaccesscontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for a comprehensive example.